# .NET 6 container not starting properly in AKS

Tags: azure-aks, .net-6.0

I have multiple .NET 6 APIs that fail to start properly in AKS.  These apps run fine in nonprod clusters, but in prod they produce no logs and refuse all connections.  If I exec into the container and try to manually start the app with `dotnet MyApp.dll` the command just hangs and there is no output.  The same image is being run in both environments as verified with the digest.

There must be some difference between the nonprod and prod clusters, but I haven't been able to identify what that difference is.  *Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Where would I look for a config difference between the environments?*

**Env details**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Kubernetes version | 1.20.9 |
| Node image version | AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2021.10.19 |
| Container runtime version | containerd://1.4.9+azure |

Using Calico network policy.

Using PrismaCloud container security.

**Manifest**

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: consumereligiblequoteclone
  namespace: consumereligiblequoteclone
  labels:
    app: consumereligiblequoteclone
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: 'true'
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: consumereligiblequoteclone
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: consumereligiblequoteclone-route
  namespace: consumereligiblequoteclone
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /consumereligiblequoteclone(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: consumereligiblequoteclone
                port:
                  number: 80
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: consumereligiblequoteclone
  namespace: consumereligiblequoteclone
  labels:
    app: consumereligiblequoteclone
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consumereligiblequoteclone
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        aadpodidbinding: msi-consumereligiblequote-p01-selector
        app: consumereligiblequoteclone
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: consumereligiblequoteclone
          image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: consumereligiblequoteclone-configmap
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 950Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 650Mi
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sleep
                  - '20'
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: consumereligiblequoteclone-allow-external
  namespace: consumereligiblequoteclone
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: ingress-nginx
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consumereligiblequoteclone
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

**Events**

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  26s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned consumereligiblequoteclone/consumereligiblequoteclone-666c8dc957-6gjb5 to aks-agentpool-18951340-vmss000000
  Normal  Pulling    26s   kubelet            Pulling image "acrcmfgprlah.azurecr.io/consumereligiblequote:20220202.3"
  Normal  Pulled     26s   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "acrcmfgprlah.azurecr.io/consumereligiblequote:20220202.3" in 104.627059ms
  Normal  Created    26s   kubelet            Created container consumereligiblequoteclone
  Normal  Started    26s   kubelet            Started container consumereligiblequoteclone
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Switch the default port from 80 to 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 \
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true

EXPOSE 5000

# Create a group and user to run the ASP.NET Core application
RUN addgroup --system dotnetappgroup && \
    adduser --system --ingroup dotnetappgroup --shell /bin/sh dotnetappuser && \
    mkdir -p /local/ && \
    chown dotnetappuser:dotnetappgroup /local && \
    chown dotnetappuser:dotnetappgroup /app

# Update Docker to run all future commands as the appuser user.
USER dotnetappuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG NuGetConfig=NuGet.Config
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api/ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api.csproj" --configfile $NuGetConfig
WORKDIR "/src/ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api"
RUN dotnet build "ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsumerEligibleQuote.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you please provide any logs, events or deployment manifestes? With your description it is hard to help.

Comment: Added manifest and events.  The logs are empty.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out some versions of Dynatrace prior to 1.231 will prevent .NET 6 apps from starting up properly.  Thank you to the nice folks over at github for helping out (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64760).